Add columns with mean of values before date, grouped in pandas
I have a table like the following



Date
Team
Score




2023-01-02
A
10


2023-01-02
A
6


2023-01-02
B
15


2023-04-07
A
17


2023-04-07
A
5


2023-04-07
B
20


2023-04-07
B
8



I need to create a column of mean score of the team at all entries before the date in that row. For example both rows with 2023-04-07 and A should have a value of 8 in the new column.
I tried using groupby.apply but no luck.

Kindly add the expected output dataframe

If you want a vectorized approach, you can get the shifted cumulative sum and count for each group of Team and Date, use that to calculate the mean for each group, then merge it back to the original dataframe.
grouped_sum = (
    df.groupby(["Team", "Date"])["Score"]
    .sum()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .shift()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .cumsum()
)
grouped_count = (
    df.groupby(["Team", "Date"])
    .size()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .shift()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .cumsum()
)
mean = (grouped_sum / grouped_count).reset_index(name="Mean")

df = df.merge(mean, on=["Date", "Team"], how="left")

         Date Team  Score  Mean
0  2023-01-02    A     10   NaN
1  2023-01-02    A      6   NaN
2  2023-01-02    B     15   NaN
3  2023-04-07    A     17   8.0
4  2023-04-07    A      5   8.0
5  2023-04-07    B     20  15.0
6  2023-04-07    B      8  15.0


Code
I agree with @e-motta method, but I think it's neat to have the code integrated.
tmp = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Team'])['Score'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
         .groupby(level=1).shift()
         .groupby(level=1).cumsum()
         .reset_index()
)

tmp:
         Date Team   sum  count
0  2023-01-02    A   NaN    NaN
1  2023-01-02    B   NaN    NaN
2  2023-04-07    A  16.0    2.0
3  2023-04-07    B  15.0    1.0

Generate Mean from tmp and merge it into df.
out = df.merge(tmp.assign(Mean=tmp.pop('sum') / tmp.pop('count')), how='left')

out
         Date Team  Score  Mean
0  2023-01-02    A     10   NaN
1  2023-01-02    A      6   NaN
2  2023-01-02    B     15   NaN
3  2023-04-07    A     17   8.0
4  2023-04-07    A      5   8.0
5  2023-04-07    B     20  15.0
6  2023-04-07    B      8  15.0


You follow these steps to achieve your desired output:
1- Sort the dataframe by Team and Date
2- Groupby Team
3- For each Team group,then groupby Date and calculate mean for each date group
df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Team'])
df['MeanScore'] = df.groupby('Team').apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby('Date')['Score'].transform(
        lambda y: x.loc[x['Date'] < y.name, 'Score'].mean()
    )
).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

Ouput:
        Date Team  Score  MeanScore
0 2023-01-02    A     10        NaN
1 2023-01-02    A      6        NaN
2 2023-01-02    B     15        NaN
3 2023-04-07    A     17        8.0
4 2023-04-07    A      5        8.0
5 2023-04-07    B     20       15.0
6 2023-04-07    B      8       15.0

